Linux reuse of ports after TCP RST
I have a set up where I do a lot of HTTPS connections to customers, and under high load some connections time out. After digging a bit I found that it happens when we or the server (same behavior in both cases) closes the connection with an RST packet and we then reuse the same ephemeral source port shortly after (usually tens of seconds).
According to all the docs and RFCs I could find (RFC 1122 section 4.2.2.13, RFC 9293 section 3.10.7.4-2.2.1) this is allowed, since as soon as you send or receive a packet with the RST bit set you should move to the CLOSED state and remove the connection state completely, making the port available for reuse right away. The problem is that the customer's firewall doesn't honor this, and drops the SYN packets of connection 2 since it believes they belong to connection 1, confirmed by customer firewall logs.
10:16:04.909342 IP my.ip.1201 > customer.ip.443: Flags [S], seq 1675405335, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 817372894 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
10:16:04.933493 IP customer.ip.443 > my.ip.1201: Flags [S.], seq 1428123841, ack 1675405336, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
10:16:04.933513 IP my.ip.1201 > customer.ip.443: Flags [.], ack 1, win 128, length 0
10:16:04.933576 IP my.ip.1201 > customer.ip.443: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 128, length 0
10:16:04.957599 IP customer.ip.443 > my.ip.1201: Flags [R.], seq 1, ack 2, win 0, length 0
10:16:17.981639 IP my.ip.1201 > customer.ip.443: Flags [S], seq 1879659950, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 817385966 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
10:16:19.011755 IP my.ip.1201 > customer.ip.443: Flags [S], seq 1879659950, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 817386997 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
10:16:21.027763 IP my.ip.1201 > customer.ip.443: Flags [S], seq 1879659950, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 817389013 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0

This problem doesn't show up under low load, since the source port numbers are semi randomized it's a low chance of port reuse before the customer's equipment has cleared the connections, but it becomes more likely the higher the load is, in a birthday problem like fashion.
For connections closed with the classical FIN/ACK process there is a TIME_WAIT state to capture stray retransmits, which also "blocks" the port from being reused, but there is no similar state for connections closed with RST since it transitions to CLOSED right away. Although this problem is caused by the customers' equipment behaving badly, is there any way for us to work around the problem by avoiding recently used ports?
I've seen this behavior on Debian with kernel 6.1.90-1 and 5.10.209-2, first seen in production with nginx, reproduced with curl (--local-port) and python (socket.create_connection() followed by socket.close())
Thanks
